# Why is it "had to" in "she had to get a new hip"?

Tags: tense, subjunctives

I saw this in a TV series (Modern Family), and I really can't understand why it's "had to" here, subjunctive maybe? so here's the context:

> Wife: I usually wear nothing when I'm in a hot tub.
>
> Husband: Then my college roommate's wife had to get a new hip.

Comment: This seems to be the past tense of *must* (which is, stricllty speaking, also *must*, but is usually written with a form of "to have to")

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the logic of the conversation, but *had to* is the perfectly ordinary past tense of *have to*, expressing obligation or necessity.